# Connecting more than one input of IC together

Tags: switches, power-electronics

I'm interested in using [SLG7NT402V](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/665/SLG7NT402r11_08272012-958081.pdf) Load Switch and I was wondering if it's okay to connect pins 3,4 together and 6,5 together.
what is the difference between this and using only one pin?
does this allow me to consume more current through pins?

here is the design that I'm intending to make using [SLG7NT402V](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/665/SLG7NT402r11_08272012-958081.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear from the datasheet that the intention is to connect the two pins together.

It does not say if you have to connect them together, or if they can be left unconnected if you dont need both pins for some reason.

The two pins should be connected together to allow for less voltage drop at given current and to allow passing more current. Connecting both pins allows also heat to be better conducted out of the chip to keep it cooler.

For small currents it may be irrelevant.
Just connect the pins together like the schematic shows.